# I want to delete a batch from file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file and contents are like :

```
|T1234
010000000000
02123456878
05122345600000000000000
07445678920000000000000
09000000000123000000000
10000000000000000000000
.T1234
|T798
013457829
0298365799
05600002222222222222222
09348977722220000000000
10000057000004578933333
.T798
```

Here one complete batch means it will start from |T and end with .T.
In the file i have 2 batches.

I want to edit this file to delete a batch for record 10(position1-2),if from position 3 till position 20 is 0 then delete the batch.

Please let me know how i can achieve this by writing a shell script or syncsort or `sed` or `awk` .

Comment: have you made an attempt?

Comment: Yes....i was trying to write a if else statement but i do not know how to put conditions and then delete lines.

Comment: _"record 10(position1-2),if from position 3 till position 20"_   For your file format, how is record number and position number defined?  Given your sample input, what do you expect for sample output?

Comment: Consider i have a file named : oldfile. Now the file content have batches start with |T as header and batch ends as.T. In between these batches i have multiple records. My condition to delete a batch is if a line start with 10 and remaining entry in that particular line is all 0 then delete the entire batch and write it into a new file. This operation should search for such entries and deletes the batches.The new file will have only those batches where the "10" record have non-zero entries.

Answer (score 0):

I am still a little unclear about exactly what you want, but I think I have it enough to give you an outline on a bash solution. The part I was unclear on is exactly which line contained the first two characters of `10` and remaining `0`'s, but it looks like that is the last line in each batch. Not knowing exactly how you wanted the batch (with the matching `10`) handled, I have simply written the remaining wanted batch(es) out to a file called `newbatch.txt` in the current working directory.

The basic outline of the script is to read each batch into a temporary array. If during the read, the `10` and `0`'s match is found, it sets a flag to delete the batch. After the last line is read, it checks the flag, if set simply outputs the batch number to delete. If the flag is not set, then it writes the batch to `./newbatch.txt`.

Let me know if your requirements are different, but this should be fairly close to a solution. The code is fairly well commented. If you have questions, just drop a comment.

```
#!/bin/bash

ifn=${1:-dat/batch.txt}  # input filename
ofn=./newbatch.txt       # output filename

:>"$ofn"                 # truncate output filename

declare -i bln=0         # batch line number
declare -i delb=0        # delete batch flag
declare -a ba            # temporary batch array

[ -r "$ifn" ] || {       # test input file readable
    printf "error: file not readable.  usage: %s filename\n" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

## read each line in input file
while read -r line || test -n "$line"; do

    printf "   %d  %s\n" $bln "$line"
    ba+=( "$line" )      # add line to array

    ## if chars 1-2 == 10 and chars 3 on == 00...
    if [ ${line:0:2} == 10 -a ${line:3} == 00000000000000000000 ]; then
        delb=1           # set delete flag
    fi

    ((bln++))            # increment line number

    ## if the line starts with '.'
    if [ ${line:0:1} == '.' ]; then

        ## if the delete batch flag is set
        if [ $delb -eq 1 ]; then
            ## do nothing (but show batch no. to delete)
            printf " => deleting batch : %s\n" "${ba[0]}"

        ## if delb not set, then write the batch to output file
        else
            printf "%s\n" ${ba[@]} >> "$ofn"
        fi

        ## reset line no., flags, and uset array.
        bln=0
        delb=0
        unset ba
    fi

done <"$ifn"

exit 0
```

**Output (to stdout)**

```
$ bash batchdel.sh
   0  |T1234
   1  010000000000
   2  02123456878
   3  05122345600000000000000
   4  07445678920000000000000
   5  09000000000123000000000
   6  10000000000000000000000
   7  .T1234
 => deleting batch : |T1234
   0  |T798
   1  013457829
   2  0298365799
   3  05600002222222222222222
   4  09348977722220000000000
   5  10000057000004578933333
   6  .T798
```

**Output (to newbatch.txt)**

```
$ cat newbatch.txt
|T798
013457829
0298365799
05600002222222222222222
09348977722220000000000
10000057000004578933333
.T798
```